# Change LaTeX chapter format

Tags: formatting

I created the sections of a book using these commands:

```
\section{Content}
```

In the PDF (and in the table of contents too) it looks like this:

1.1 Content

Instead of "1.1 Content" I want this to say "Content 1.1". How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\enspace\thesection}
\titlecontents{section}[15pt]{}%
{}{\partname{}}%
{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}\contentspage}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%header & footer
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.8pt}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{chapter}
    \section{Content}
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should take a ook at the `titlesec` package

Comment: Yes. I'm using it in my .tex file too.

Comment: `\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\enspace\thesection}`, with the `explicit` option, should do more or less what you want.

Comment: Thank you! It works. However, in the table of contents and the header the old style is still used. Is there anyway to change this?

Comment: See the documentation of the companion  `titletoc`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to ask another question if you can't make it work.

Comment: I tried this: \titlecontents{section}[5pt]{}%
{}{\partname{} }%
{\enspace\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}\contentspage}%

but the headers are still not updating. Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you compile twice (the .toc fie has to be updated)? If it doesn't work, please post a minimal, yet compilable, code that we can test.

Comment: Yes, I compiled it twice. I posted the sample code.

Comment: I changed the sample code so you can see the issue of the header showing "1.1 Content" on page 5 instead of "Content 1.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to use a package to extend functionality. However, if you're in a pinch, you can use the following approach that manipulates/changes the basic functions `\@sect` and `\l@section` to achieve what you're after.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.8pt}

\makeatletter
% Update placement of sectional units within text
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\interlinepenalty \@M #8}% <search>
  {\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}% <search>
  {\interlinepenalty \@M #8}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\quad\csname the#1\endcsname}

% Reverse display of numbering and title in ToC
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else 
    \protect \numberline {\csname the#1\endcsname }%
   \fi #7}% <search>
  {#7 \protect\quad \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname
   \fi}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

% Change section mark in headers
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\MakeUppercase{#1\ \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\z@ \thesection}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Since we're updating `\@sect`, the changes are reflected in every sectional unit used (`\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use both `titletoc` and `tocloft` to avoid conflicts.
 Here  is a simple solution. As I didn't understand what `\partname{}` was doing in your code, I removed it.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\enspace\thesection}
\titlecontents{section}[15pt]{}%
{}{}%\partname{}
{\enspace\thecontentslabel\hspace{0.2em}\titlerule*[0.67pc]{.}\contentspage}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%header & footer
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.8pt}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{chapter}
    \section{Content}
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: Here is a code which replaces `fancyhdr` with `titleps` and does what you want in the header:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit, pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{#1\enspace\thesection}
\titlecontents{section}[15pt]{}%
{}{}%
{\enspace\thecontentslabel\hspace{0.2em}\titlerule*[0.67pc]{.}\contentspage}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\setheadrule{0.8pt}
\headrule
\sethead[\thepage][][\ifthechapter{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername} \thechapter\quad}{}\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}]%
{\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitle}\enspace\thesection}{}{\thepage}
}%
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{chapter}
    \section{Content}
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext
    \pagebreak
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The headers still show 1.1 Content instead of Content 1.1. :(

Comment: I didn't look at the heasers, but I think it will be simpler to do with  `titleps`  (load `titlesec` with option `[pagestyles]`).

Comment: @furfur: please see my edit for the header problem.

Comment: Thank you! It is very interesting